# Partially-flattening a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, flatten, array-column

What would be a good way to transform an array that looks like:

```
Array (
    [0] = Array (
            [0] = Array (
                    [key] = val
                    [key2] = val2
                )

        )
    [1] = Array (
            [0] = Array (
                    [key] = val
                    [key2] = val2
                )

        )
)
```

to

```
Array (
    [0] = Array (
            [key] = val
            [key] = val2
        )
    [1] = Array (
            [key] = val
            [key] = val2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be a rather neat way of doing it

```
$output=array_map('array_shift', $input);
```

This uses [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) to call [array_shift](http://php.net/array_shift) on each each element of the input array, which will give you the first element of each sub-array! Nice little one-liner, no?

Nice as it is, it's not terribly efficient as array_shift does more work than we need - a simple loop is actually far faster (I just did a quick benchmark on an array with 1000 elements and this was around 6x faster)

```
$output=array();
foreach ($input as $element){
    $output[]=$element[0];
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough I was doing that too, expecting it to be faster - it was about the same as array_shift though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new=array();
foreach($array as $a){
  $new[]=array_shift($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new=array();
foreach ($array as $a){
$new[]=$a[0];
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: Don't you mean $new[] = $a[0];?

Comment: Plus should not you first create the new array? `$new = array();` ?

Comment: with code snippets I assume some of the basics are already understood.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is `$my_array` and has 2 elements, you can:

```
$my_array = array_merge($my_array[0], $my_array[1]);
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone over thought this one.  This is exactly what `array_column()` does.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/379df8ac2ea46a5efabb4681e02bf8e934408ab4))

```
$array=[
    [
        ['key'=>'val','key2'=>'val2']
    ],
    [
        ['key'=>'val','key2'=>'val2']
    ]
];
var_export(array_column($array,0));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'val',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'val',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  ),
)
```